# What to choose for json data

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want to return json data e like in the following link.
http://paramquery.com/demos/pagingGetOrders?cur_page=1&records_per_page=20&sortBy=orderID&dir=asc&_=1391574981665

What type of method or service i need to create for achieve this and Url pattern should same as above .

Please help me .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wcf rest service for that:

Wcf service can return json data from your method

this is the link for that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx

Comment: http://paramquery.com/demos/pagingGetOrders?cur_page=1&records_per_page=20&sortBy=orderID&dir=asc&_=1391574981665

I thinks this url is not use any webservicea or wcf service because url not contains any .svc/asmx extension.

Comment: you can change url  using this statement   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/getallcategory", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Comment: uritemplate is a path for the service